# bulk insert with format file sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I would like to create a stored procedure that imports a txt file into an existing table using a format file and also update certain fields that will be null in the import. The import file will just update one column and I need to manually assign values for the other columns.

```
bulk insert QueryData from 'E:\TrackInputLogs\NMSLog.txt'
with(FORMATFILE = 'E:\TrackInputLogs\NMSFormat.fmt', 
ROWTERMINATOR='\n')
```

I need to update the following columns as follows at the same time

```
dateimported = getdate()
idkey = asdfg
importmethod = manual
```

oh by the way, this is an existing table and I do not want to delete current contents but also the import will update the fields where the idkey matches the values associated with the file contents.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the Chinese characters and all it came down in the end was changing SQLNCHAR to SQLCHAR in the format file...

```
9.0
4
1 SQLCHAR 0 10  ","    1 Field1 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
2 SQLCHAR 0 10  ","    2 Field2 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3 SQLCHAR 0 6   ","    3 Field3 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4 SQLCHAR 0 100 "\r\n" 4 Field4 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```